# Grade de horarios com PHP

Tags: php

Estou tendo um pequeno problema com meu código, que gera agenda de horários, ele não ta inserindo o ultimo horário.

tipo  07:00 as  10:00 intervalo de 30 min
mas ele so vai ate 09:30 nao grava os 10:00

Esse é o meu código :

```
<?
date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");
$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$bd=mysql_select_db("test",$con);
//$hora_inicio = $_POST['hora_inicio'];  
//$hora_final = $_POST['hora_final'];
$hora_inicio = "07:00";  
$hora_final = "10:00";             
$ini = strtotime($hora_inicio);
$fim = strtotime($hora_final);
$atu = $ini;
$i = 1;
for ($atu = $ini ;  $atu < $fim; $atu = strtotime('+30 minutes', $atu)) {
$hr_agendamento = date('H:i', $atu);
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO agenda (id_agenda,hr_agendamento) VALUES('','$hr_agendamento')");                        
}
echo"agenda criada";
?>
```

Comment: Seu código não veio... Poste o código para que possamos ajudar

Comment: <?
date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");

$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$bd=mysql_select_db("test",$con);

$hora_inicio = "07:00";  
$hora_final = "10:00";                
$ini = strtotime($hora_inicio);
$fim = strtotime($hora_final);
$atu = $ini;
$i = 1;
for ($atu = $ini ;  $atu < $fim; $atu = strtotime('+30 minutes', $atu)) {
$hr_agendamento = date('H:i', $atu);
                       
            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO agenda (id_agenda,hr_agendamento) VALUES('','$hr_agendamento')");                           
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso esta acontecendo porque você esta comparando em seu `for` na sua linha **13**, se `$atu` é menor que `$fim`.

> for ($atu = $ini ;  $atu **<** $fim; $atu = strtotime('+30 minutes', $atu))

Para que ele faça o que você quer, você deve comparar também se `$atu` é igual à `$fim`.

> for ($atu = $ini ;  $atu **<=** $fim; $atu = strtotime('+30 minutes', $atu))

Ficando assim seu loop:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");
$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$bd=mysql_select_db("test",$con);
//$hora_inicio = $_POST['hora_inicio'];  
//$hora_final = $_POST['hora_final'];
$hora_inicio = "07:00";  
$hora_final = "10:00";             
$ini = strtotime($hora_inicio);
$fim = strtotime($hora_final);
$atu = $ini;
$i = 1;
for ($atu = $ini ;  $atu <= $fim; $atu = strtotime('+30 minutes', $atu)) {
    $hr_agendamento = date('H:i', $atu);
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO agenda (id_agenda,hr_agendamento) VALUES('','$hr_agendamento')");                        
}
echo "agenda criada";
```

Você pode ver funcionando aqui no [ideone](https://ideone.com/C0O27d).

Comment: realmente funcionou... agora eu to tentando troca a hora intervalo(+30) por uma variavel mas nao ta dando certo . tem como me explicar , por que queria passra esse valor via post tambem mas nao ta passando ele gera um loop infinito ou quase

Comment: Posso sim, para isso abra uma nova pergunta com o detalhe e código.