# variavel intervalo hora php

Tags: php

Gostaria de acrescentar esta variável intervalo a este código mas não estou conseguindo , se puderem me ajudar serei muito grato.

Achei este código na Internet e adaptei pro meu sistema, porém esbarrei nesta questão do intervalo.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");
$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$bd=mysql_select_db("test",$con);
//$hora_inicio = $_POST['hora_inicio'];  
//$hora_final = $_POST['hora_final'];
$hora_inicio = "07:00";  
$hora_final = "10:00";  
$int ="00:30";// variavel que define o intervalo           
$ini = strtotime($hora_inicio);
$fim = strtotime($hora_final);
$atu = $ini;
$i = 1;
for ($atu = $ini ;  $atu <= $fim; $atu = strtotime('+30 minutes', $atu)) {
    $hr_agendamento = date('H:i', $atu);
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO agenda (id_agenda,hr_agendamento) VALUES('','$hr_agendamento')");                        
}
echo "agenda criada";
```

Comment: mesmo assim a pergunta editada não sei bem o que pretendes queres inserir com um intervalo de tempo ?

Comment: precisa ser mais claro e específico no que queres

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Grade de horarios com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230713/grade-de-horarios-com-php)

Comment: Creio que seja diferente pelo fato de estar querendo acrescentar o intervalo. mas de fato é o mesmo código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente dessa forma:

```php
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$bd  = mysqli_select_db("test", $con);

$hora_inicio = new DateTime('07:00');
$hora_final  = new DateTime('10:00');

while($hora_inicio->add(new DateInterval('PT30M')) < $hora_final) {   
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO agenda(hr_agendamento) VALUES('".$hora_inicio->format('H:i')."')");                        
}

echo "Agenda criada!";
```

Answer (score 0):

Para tornar dinâmico o intervalo basta utilizar a variável com apenas a quantidade de minutos, desta forma:

```
$int ="30";// variavel que define o intervalo em minutos
```

E no seu For, deve utilizar a variável $int no lugar do "30", concatenando com o +,  desta forma:

```
for ($atu = $ini ;  $atu <= $fim; $atu = strtotime('+'.$int.' minutes', $atu)) {
```

Substitua as linhas indicadas e faça o teste. Agora você pode trocar o valor da variável e irá gerar os horários no intervalo desejado.

Todo o código:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");
$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$bd=mysql_select_db("test",$con);
//$hora_inicio = $_POST['hora_inicio'];  
//$hora_final = $_POST['hora_final'];
$hora_inicio = "07:00";  
$hora_final = "10:00";  
$int ="30";// variavel que define o intervalo em minutos           
$ini = strtotime($hora_inicio);
$fim = strtotime($hora_final);
$atu = $ini;
$i = 1;
for ($atu = $ini ;  $atu <= $fim; $atu = strtotime('+'.$int.' minutes', $atu)) {
    $hr_agendamento = date('H:i', $atu);
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO agenda (id_agenda,hr_agendamento) VALUES('','$hr_agendamento')");                        
}
echo "agenda criada";
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode simplificar a criação dos periodos de datas ou horas com a classe `DatePeriod` no construção são necessários três argumentos o início do período, o intervalo e o fim.

Se possível migre seu código com as funções `mysql_` para as `mysqli_`.

```
$inicio = new DateTime(@"07:00");
$fim = new DateTime(@"10:00");
$fim->modify('+30 minutes');

$periodo = new DatePeriod($inicio, new DateInterval('PT30M'), $fim);


foreach ($periodo as $item) {
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO agenda (hr_agendamento) VALUES('%s')", $item->format('H:i'));
    mysql_query($sql) or print 'falha em: '. mysql_error();
}
```